# Date time Data type mismatch access

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with this statement i am Trying to retrieve data from  a table based on the date but its keep telling me that there is a data type mismatch

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", null);
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("select name from Items where exp_dat='" + dt + "'", con);
            System.Data.DataTable dt4 = new System.Data.DataTable();
            OleDbDataAdapter Adapter4 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2);
            Adapter4.Fill(dt4);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameters to prevent sql injection and conversion/localization issues:

```
var dt4 = new System.Data.DataTable();
using(var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select name from Items where exp_dat=@exp_dat", con))
{
    DateTime dt;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@exp_dat", OleDbType.Date).Value = dt;
        da.Fill( dt4 );
    }
}
```

Note that

- `con.Open`/`con.Close` is not needed with `OlebDataAdapter.Fill(table)`
- you should always use the `using`-statement on objects that are disposable(implement `IDisposable`), that ensures that all unmanaged resources are disposed, even in case of an error
- you should use `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` as parameter for `ParseExact` since `null` is replaced with the current culture. If that does not use `/` as date separator `TryParseExact` cannot parse this string(presuming that `textBox1.Text` is something like `28/09/2015`)

Comment: I used your code and the error is fixed but its not retrieving any data